# Upper bound time complexity

Tags: time-complexity

I have an algorithm that for $n$ iterations performs some insertions into a set and priority queue. I know that in the last iteration (the case where time complexity is always worst), the time complexity is $O(n \log n)$. I also have more in-depth time complexity analysis if needed but the thing is: The time complexity of any iteration will never be worse than the time complexity of the final iteration.

Is it safe to say that the $n$ iterations are all bounded by the worst iteration (being the final one, which runs in $O(n \log n)$ or is the full analysis needed to proof that the whole algorithm would run in $O(n \log n)$.

Comment: I don't follow that for $n$ iterations where the final one is in time $O(n \log n)$, the overall time is $\in O(n \log n)$, too.

Comment: I can't understand what you are asking.  What do you mean by "the $n$ iterations are bounded" - what are you trying to bound?  The running time of a single iteration?  The running time to perform all $n$ iterations?  In any case, the answer is probably trivial.  If I tell you that I have $n$ numbers, and the largest is at most 1000, you should be able to answer questions on your own like: what is an upper bound on every number?  what is an upper bound on the sum of the numbers?